# GenericDAO doesnt delete from database

Tags: java, jpa, sql-delete, dao

I'm trying to delete an entity by using my `genericDAO`'s method delete. I have a `RessourcenbuchungDAO` which uses the delete function of my `genericDAO` and I dont get an error, it should be working but my database doesnt change. In my `EntityDAO` the same delete method works just fine, I can't find the mistake I hope someone can help.

My GenericDAOs delete method:

```
   protected boolean delete(Object id, Class<T> classe){

        //Versuchen objekt zu lesen
        T entityToBeRemoved = em.getReference(classe, id);
        try {
            em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
            return true;


} catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+id.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

My method to call the delete method of genericDAO

```
public boolean schuelerSectionEntfernen(int buchungsId) {
    Ressourcenbuchung aRessourcenbuchung = ressourcenbuchungsDAO.find(buchungsId);
    System.out.println("Buchung " + aRessourcenbuchung.getBuchungsId() + " wurde zum Loeschen gefunden.");
    if (aRessourcenbuchung == null)
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    else {
        System.out.println("Test Loeschen");
        ressourcenbuchungsDAO.delete(aRessourcenbuchung);
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

My Ressourcenbuchungen class

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "HA2_RESSOURCENBUCHUNGEN")
public class Ressourcenbuchung implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2489159602487241894L;

    private int schuelerId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Section section;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MUSIKSCHULE_BUCHUNG_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MUSIKSCHULE_BUCHUNG_ID", sequenceName = "MUSIKSCHULE_SEQ_BUCHUNG_ID", allocationSize = 1)
    private int buchungsId;
```

Comment: Does it work if you wrap the delete in a transaction? Like em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.remove(...);
  em.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: @dementis if I try this method I now suddenly get the Error from my try catch. I already tested if the entityToBeRemoved is empty but its not. If i try to delete it manually in my database it works just fine.

Comment: if you System.out.println() the exception that gets caught, what does it say? It might hint why em.remove is failing